# Cannot find name 'Highcharts'.ts(2304)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, highcharts

I am getting issue in angular "Cannot find name 'Highcharts'.ts(2304)"
how to solve this problem
also I used CDN for high chart
I installed

"npm install --save highcharts"

begin snippet:  hide: false console: true babel: false

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {

            opposite: true,

            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            alternateGridColor: null,
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' m/s'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                lineWidth: 4,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 5
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                pointInterval: 3600000, // one hour
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 4, 31, 0, 0, 0)
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Hestavollane',
            data: [0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1.3, 1.5, 2.9, 1.9, 2.6, 1.6, 3, 4, 3.6, 4.5, 4.2, 4.5, 4.5, 4, 3.1, 2.7, 4, 2.7, 2.3, 2.3, 4.1, 7.7, 7.1, 5.6, 6.1, 5.8, 8.6, 7.2, 9, 10.9, 11.5, 11.6, 11.1, 12, 12.3, 10.7, 9.4, 9.8, 9.6, 9.8, 9.5, 8.5, 7.4, 7.6]

        }],
        navigation: {
            menuI
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

temStyle: {
fontSize: '10px'
}
}

```
    }

);
```

language: html

```
 <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

end snippet

Comment: ... well, did you import the module from the .ts file (component) where you are trying to use it : `import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts'` ... (they have wrapper library for Anglar useage in particular : `https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular` ) ...

Comment: Yes I tried * as Highcharts from 'highcharts' ... (they have wrapper library for Anglar useage in particular : https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular ) ...

Comment: Hi @CHANDAN KUMAR, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? You can use this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line as a base.